# How to ensure file upload works with video using loopj AndroidAsyncHttp?

Tags: php, android, video, android-async-http, loopj

I am trying to upload a video file to my server from my android app using loopj AndroidAsyncHttp library. Uploading an image gives a "Success: 200" response whereas attempting to upload a video give either a 500 or 302 error response. This is my upload method:

```
    private void uploadVideoTwo(String filePath){

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        File myFile = new File(filePath);
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        try {
            params.put("file", myFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Params Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        client.post(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Success: " + String.valueOf(statusCode));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failure: " + String.valueOf(statusCode));
            }
        });


    }
```

My PHP code looks like this:

```
    <?php 

$result = array("success" => $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$name= $_FILES['file']['name'];

$tmp_name= $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$path= "uploads/";

if (isset($name)) {

    if (empty($name))
    {
        $result = array("success" => "error uploading file");
    }
    else
    {
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path . $name)) {
            $result = array("success" => "File successfully uploaded");
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Android Studio logcat shows progress percentage during upload of video file but gives error response after it gets to 100%. I am using an intent to open the camera to capture a video with a limit of 30 seconds and a size limit of 5 mb. I have no idea why uploading an image works fine but not a video using the same script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in your `php.ini` file. Default value is only 2 megabytes, so you should change it to something more appropriate.

To find out the location of `php.ini` on your own host just insert a call to `phpinfo()` inside any available script on your site and see the output in your browser.

For popular cloud platforms:

On Google Cloud Engine (standard or flexible environments) put `php.ini` file to your project's root (alongside `app.yaml`) with these lines inside:

`post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 128M`

On Heroku put `.user.ini` file with the same content as above in your app's root directory.

Comment: It worked on one server but not the intended server. Could the htaccess file having deny All in it cause it not to happen?

Comment: What is the value of `upload_max_filesize` in `phpinfo()` output of your server in question?

Comment: Max file upload size is 125M

Comment: And `post_max_size` из the same or bigger, or `0`?

Comment: post_max_size is the same value

Comment: Then it should be execution time issue, as Kurt wrote below. Although I'm not sure if upload time counts as execution.

Check php and webserver error log, is anything helpful there?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like either a timeout or a filesize issue. Default execution time of a php script is 30 seconds. Change it to i.e. 300 (5 minutes) in your php.ini file.

```
; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_execution_time=300

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize=32M
```

Also, enable error reporting by putting the following in the very beginning of your php script. It will give you a more detailed description of what is going wrong.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```